# Does anyone know the name of this 3D CGI animated sci-fi superhero show set in space?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, super-hero, animation

Okay, this is an animated show I watched years ago when I was a child, I have forgotten its name long ago and now I would like to see it again.

I don't know whether the show was a TV series or a movie, but I watched it via DVD; I don't know the exact year when I watched the show, but I am absolutely sure it was before 2010, almost absolutely sure it was before 2008, the show was in 3D, it could be either CGI or stop motion, and I think it was more likely to be CGI.

The show could either be of American origin or Japanese origin, the characters in the show were realistically proportional, the show was set in space, on a space station or a space ship or an asteroid, I am not sure which, though I am 99% sure it wasn't anywhere near planet Earth, and the characters (especially the protagonists) weren't humans, they were organic humanoid aliens, and part of some kind of military organization, and they were superhero-ish, though they used guns.

The setting was either Science Fiction or Science Fantasy, and the scenes looked futuristic.

Although I am not sure what the show was, I am sure what it wasn't. It wasn't Star Wars, Star Trek, Starship Troopers, Transformers, Gundam and Ultraman.

Can anyone identify what was the show I had watched? I am sorry I can't provide any further details, it's been at least 12 years since, and I don't have photographic memory. If someone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [*Shadow Raiders*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0169510/)?

> The inhabitants of four mutually hostile worlds must unite their forces to face the grave menace of an invading planet & population.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I Google searched Shadow Raiders and looked at the images and recognized the characters. Thank you so much!